# Removing rows of character strings that are subsets of a larger character string

Tags: r, subset, apriori, arules

I'm using the below codes to create association rules for a project;

```
RawData_Kicks_Rules <- apriori(RawData_Kicks_ALLKICKS, parameter = list(supp = 0.005, conf = 0.5, minlen=3, maxlen=9))

RawData_Limiter <- which(colSums(is.subset(RawData_Kicks_Rules,RawData_Kicks_Rules))>1)

RawData_Kicks_Rules.sub <-RawData_Kicks_Rules[-RawData_Limiter]
```

The goal from the last two lines of code is to identify and remove any rules that are a part of a larger existing rule. For example;

**{Disposal Source=Free Kick,Kick Target=Open,Direction=Sideward} => {Kick Distance=0-20}**

**{Disposal Source=Free Kick,Kick Target=Open,Direction=Sideward,Disposal Pressure=None} => {Kick Distance=0-20}**

In this output, ideally the first rule would have been removed since it is already a part of the the second rule.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: It could be a problem with the formating of your data. Hard to say without the data. Check if `summary(RawData_Kicks_Rules)` makes sense (especially the item labels). If that does not solve the problem, then post an example here with the data.